# Arduino C++ passing objects as parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

I'm writing a little Timer class in C++ for Arduino, but I can't pass its instance by reference correctly without being cloned.

Here is the Timer.h :

```
#ifndef Timer_h
#define Timer_h

class Timer
{
    public:
        long t = 0 ;
        long tMax = 60000 ;

        Timer() ;
        bool clocked(long n) ;
        void wait(long ms) ;
} ;

#endif
```

And here the Timer.cpp :

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Timer.h"

Timer::Timer() {}

bool Timer::clocked(long n)
{
    return (t % n) == 0 ;
}

void Timer::wait(long ms)
{
    t += ms ;
    delay(ms) ;

    Serial.println(t) ;

    if (t >= tMax) t = 0 ;
}
```

---

And here is a main.ino example :

```
#include "Timer.h"
#include "ABC.h"

Timer timer = Timer() ;
ABC abc = ABC() ;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600) ;
    abc.setTimer(timer) ;
}

void loop()
{
    timer.wait(100) ;
    Serial.println(timer.t) ; // 100
    Serial.println(abc.timer.t) ; // 0, should be 100

    timer.wait(50) ;
    abc.timer.wait(100) ;
    Serial.println(timer.t) ; // 150, should be 250
    Serial.println(abc.timer.t) ; // 100, should be 250
}
```

... with the ABC.h example :

```
#include "Timer.h"

class ABC
{
    public:
        Timer timer ;

        ABC() ;
        void setTimer(const Timer& tm) ;
} ;
```

... and ABC.cpp :

```
#include "Timer.h"

ABC::ABC() {}

void ABC::setTimer(const Timer& tm)
{
    timer = tm ;
}
```

---

I surely miss some `&` or `*` somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: I'm sure you could have narrowed this down some...

Comment: BTW this `Timer timer = Timer() ;`, `ABC abc = ABC() ;` stuff is completely unnecessary. Just declare the objects normally without the initialiser.

Comment: Yeah you're copying `Timer`s everywhere. Not sure what you expected to happen. Since you can't reseat references your best bet is probably storing a pointer inside `ABC`, but ew.

Comment: Alright for the initialisers. :) So what should I do then ? I wish I could share the same instance for everyone by passing it, just like in higher level languages.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you have an instance of a timer in ABC, and you're trying to do set a reference to it. I think you're better off with a pointer to a timer inside of ABC and then pass the reference to the external timer (e.g. setTimer(&timer) )

Comment: @SJoshi: That's a pointer, not a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is a high level language. It supports value semantics and reference semantics, however you have chosen to use value semantics by writing:

```
Timer timer ;
```

in your class definition.  If instead you want to use reference semantics you could replace this with `Timer *timer;`, or a smart pointer such as `std::shared_ptr<Timer> p_timer;` or `std::unique_ptr<Timer> p_timer;`.

Using a C++ reference (i.e. `Timer &timer;`) is possible but probably not appropriate to your situation as this reference can only be bound at the point of creating the `ABC`.

Using `shared_ptr` will give you the closest match to object references in Java, for example. Of course this means you will have to create the `Timer` object you are binding to it with `make_shared<Timer>()` or equivalent.

Using `unique_ptr` is appropriate for when there should only be one reference to the timer in existence at any one time.

Using raw pointers has the smallest memory footprint, however you must then take great care to ensure that the `Timer` object exists for the whole duration of the `ABC` object's lifetime, and is deleted after that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying things with what you said, but I still have different issues as the Timer element isn't a kind of singleton. In the ABC file, I set `Timer *timer ;` and `::setTimer(Timer tm) { *timer = tm }`, then call `timer->wait(50)` but still not working. P.S.: It seems I can't include memory header with Arduino, so no `std` available.

Comment: @Tot `setTimer(Timer tm)` means to pass the timer by value. If you want to pass by reference then use one of the reference options I mentioned.  `*timer = tm;` is obviously bad as you have not made `timer` point anywhere, and it also copies by value which you said you don't want to do.  IDK what you mean about singletons. There is only one timer mentioned in your post. Your post reads as if you have created a timer somewhere and you want to make ABC use that timer. If that is not the case then update your post to try and explain what you are doing.

Comment: "Your post reads as if you have created a timer somewhere and you want to make ABC use that timer." That's exactly what I want to do, and that's what I meant with "singleton". But I'm still puzzled with this whole.

Comment: @Tot you need to use one of the passing techniques with reference semantics (both when calling the function, and having your class hold the timer by reference).  If you can't use the smart pointers then use the raw pointer.

Comment: Okay, it works now. I retried to add pointer references and now it works. I forgot to add a `&` for `abc.setTimer(&timer) ;`. Thank you for your answer !